Modify colors of PrimeVue with vite
I have a Vue-3 project where I use Vite and PrimeVue-4.
I would like to change the entire color pallete, but cannot find any good reference for how to do it.
I tried the following:
vite.config.ts:
export default defineConfig({
  :
  :
  css: {
    preprocessorOptions: {
      scss: {
        additionalData: `
          @import "./src/styles/myapp_theme.scss";
        `
      }
    }
  },

myapp_theme.scss:
$primary-color: #f15b5a;
$secondary-color: #f2c960;

$p-button-outlined-primary-border-color: blue;
$p-button-outlined-primary-color: blue;

But I still have #10b981 for: (inspected in browser developer console)
.p-button-outlined {
   :
    color: var(--p-button-outlined-primary-color);
}

===== UPDATE ======
I also tried to set the color directly:
App.vue:
<style lang="scss">
$p-button-outlined-primary-border-color: blue;
$p-button-outlined-primary-color: blue;
</style>

But it does't work neither.
I guess it has to do with the order of declarations, because if I use this code:
<style lang="scss">
    $mycolor1: #f15b5a;
    $mycolor2: #f2c960;

    h1 {
      color:$mycolor1
    }
</style>

it does applied on the <h1> tag.
